# Finding the radius and height of a cone inside a cone

Tags: calculus, volume, geometry

I need to find the volume of a metal cone that is hollow with a thickness of 2cm. The radius of the big cone is 8cm and the height is 12. The thickness determents the radius, and height of the little cone inside. How do i find the radius and height of the little cone so i can correctly find the volume of the metal?

(The cone has a base and is not like a ice-cream cone)

$$V = (\frac{1}{3}\pi R^2 H) - (\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h)$$

Image showing cone inside a cone:

http://i62.tinypic.com/i1y41z.png

Comment: I thought if i find the angle where the big radius line is. To then find the angle in the top of the cone. Divide that by two. Use Pythagoras so i find the height from the tip of the small cone to the tip of the big cone. Then use that angle inside the small cone. Since they should be the same? Would that be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vertical cross section of the solid gives two similar triangles, one inside the other. The base of the larger triangle is $16$ and its height is $12$; the base of the smaller triangle is $12$ and its height is, say, $h$.

$h$/$6$ = $12$/$8$

which gives $h$ = $9$.

Now the volume can be found using the formula stated in the problem.